# Extract numerical value from PDF chart to a variable in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, tm

I'm trying to pull a numerical value from a chart that's been embedded in a pdf.

I tried the two methods below, but I was able to convert every other information into xlsx except the line chart information

Link to the pdf:
http://blog.mass.gov/publichealth/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/01/Weekly-Flu-Report-01-19-2018.pdf

The value that I need to pull into a variable [image]

1st Method

```
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(xlsx)
set.seed(100)
tx <- pdf_text("flureport.pdf")
tx2 <- unlist(str_split(tx, "[\\r\\n]+"))
tx3 <- str_split_fixed(str_trim(tx2), "\\s{2,}", 5)

write.xlsx(tx3, file="ds.xlsx")
```

2nd Method

```
library('tm')
file <- 'flureport.pdf'
Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))
corpus <- VCorpus(URISource(file), 
                  readerControl = list(reader = Rpdf))
corpus.array <- content(content(corpus)[[1]])


c<-data.frame(corpus.array)
write.xlsx(c, file="x.xlsx")
```

Both the xlsx that I wrote didnt contain any chart information, so that I can fetch the value

Comment: It's a little hard to say for sure, but I'd guess that number is just pixels in the graph.  That means you'd need OCR to convert it to digits and interpret it, and it's going to be hard to tell the OCR routine which number to convert:  there are also dates and axis labels.  So you'd have to mark it yourself; but by this point, wouldn't it be easier just to type the number?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me, not sure if it would work for all the cases but it did work work in this particular case.
Thanks @user2554330 for mentioning OCR

```
    library(pdftools)
    library(stringr)
    library(tesseract)
    library(magick)
    library(magrittr)

list <- c('http://blog.mass.gov/publichealth/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/01/Weekly-Flu-Report-01-19-2018.pdf')
sapply(list, function(x)
  pdf_convert(x, format = "png", pages = NULL, filenames = NULL, dpi = 300, opw = "", upw = "", verbose = TRUE))



text <- image_read("Weekly-Flu-Report-01-19-2018_1.png") %>%
  image_resize("2000") %>%
  image_convert(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
  image_trim() %>%
  image_ocr()


a<-print(text)


massili<-regmatches(a, gregexpr("\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,1} %", a))[[1]]
```